# Dynamic JSON path filtering in PostgreSQL 9.6

Tags: postgresql

I have a somewhat odd JSONB structure in my database to accomodate different possible overrides to common fields. The tricky thing is that I want to query based on those overrides. Here's a sample of my data:

```
{
    "title": "bar",
    "_override": {
        "o1": {
            "title": "baz"
        },
        "o2": {
            "title": "foo"
        }
    }
},
{
    "title": "baz",
    "_override": {
        "o2": {
            "title": "bar"
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the query I managed to get:

```
select distinct
  id,
  metadata,
  metadata->'_override'->jsonb_object_keys(metadata->'_override')->>'title' as title
from
  public.brands
cross join
  jsonb_each(metadata->'_override')
where
  title = 'foo'
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting `ERROR: column "title" does not exist`, even though `title` is a valid alias. I've tried adding the json_object_keys call to the WHERE clause, but then `ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE".

I feel that I am missing something in this approach. Maybe I should re-structure the data somehow or there's an easy way to traverse dynamic JSONB paths? I couldn't find anything about wildcards, only this complex query that accounts for multiple nesting levels: https://obartunov.livejournal.com/193870.html

EDIT: Based on feedback on the comments, here's the approach using a CTE.

```
with CurrentOverride as
(
  select distinct
     uuid,
     metadata,
     jsonb_object_keys(metadata->'_override') as override
  from
     brands
  cross join
     jsonb_each(metadata->'_override')
)
select
  uuid,
  metadata
from
  CurrentOverride
where
  metadata->'_override'->override->>'title' = 'foo'
```

But still not sure if it is the best approach.

Comment: You can't access a column alias in the where clause. You need to wrap the whole query to be able to do that.

Comment: With a window function?

Comment: It's not clear to me how the override should be applied. Does `'baz'` override  `'foo'`? Or does `'bar'` override `'baz'`? Is that one single "element" that is overwritten three times (and what is the applicable title then)? Or are that two different elements within the same column value where in the first one `bar is overwritten by `baz` which in turn is overwritten by `foo`? And in the second one `baz` is overwritten by `bar`? Or are that in fact two rows in the table with two different JSON values?